# .NET Core Publish Exe with incorrect modified date?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, windows-services, exe, publish

I'm having an issue with the publication of my Windows Service.

The .exe that is output has a weird modified date on it and not sure how / why it is being changed, I think it is the cause for issues I'm having running this exe Live.

I need to confirm that my code changes are truly part of this exe.

Grateful for any experience anyone has with this, thank you in advance!

Publication Options:

[image]

File Directory:

[image]

File Properties:

[image]

Comment: If you want to be sure you built a new version... why not use version numbers? (also, eesh, a developer who keeps file extensions hidden...)

Comment: I didn't think of that I'll try that and haha it's a new machine, I will tend to this travesty immediately!!

Comment: Literally, that .exe is a variant of `dotnet.exe`, a thin launcher to launch `FidessaFileFeed.dll` which is the true main executable. That's why the last modified date is in 2018 (when Microsoft released that .NET Core runtime). That date is quite accurate, just not in the way you expected.

Comment: @LexLi If you want to make that the answer to this question I'd  be happy to accept it, as it is the only sensible answer I've seen online!

Comment: @Nyerguds After using your suggestion I could determine the .exe was being built, turns out I needed to include the 'CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies' to PropertyGroup in my .csproj file as I was missing a dll for a nuget reference!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

The design of .NET Core self-contained deployment is like this,

- Generate everything needed for framework dependent deployment.
- Then add some extra files.

Therefore, the main executable is always `FidessaFileFeed.dll` (FDD or SCD), and `FidessaFileFeed.exe` is merely a launcher copied from .NET Core runtime folder (I think it is just a variant of `dotnet.exe`).

Naturally you see that the time stamp of `FidessaFileFeed.dll` matches your expectation, while `FidessaFileFeed.exe` matches other files from the runtime (like `hostfxr.dll`) and dates back to 2018 (the time when Microsoft released this runtime version).